# How to push commits from one repo to another on GitHub Desktop?

Tags: git, github, repo

This could be complete lack of knowledge on my end but I've tried this a few times and can't seem to figure it out.

I have a dev repo and a prod repo. Idea is, make changes on dev, commit to dev repo, test on dev site, push to prod repo if all goes well. Does anyone know how to actually do this on GitHub Desktop or does this need to be done through the Git CLI? I've googled around but can't find anything obvious for this.

If this is a moronic way of doing this, I'm also open to some best practice alignment from more experienced people than myself.

Thanks!

Comment: Normally you would have a branching strategy. https://www.gitkraken.com/learn/git/best-practices/git-branch-strategy

Comment: However if you want to do it the way you have written it you have to set up multiple remotes instead https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote